# How to rewrite urls in zf2 based on database values

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I want my url  `mydomain.com/user/id` or `mydomain.com/user?id=somevalue` to be redirected to  `mydomain.com/user/username` . Just like facebook redirect my url from accountId to username. Currently if I use any of the url then it will fetch the correct user profile. id and username is unique for a particular user and in my database I have saved username corresponding to a user id. The route which I am using are

```
    'UserProfile' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/user[/:id]',
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'UserProfile\Controller\UserProfile',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
```

In the controller it makes an api call using username or userId which it receives  and return data to the view model. I also want that only after redirection profile will be visible to user.Is it possible only from htaccess or it can be done using some routing? Any example or any lead will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in the controller after finding the user with the given ID:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user',array ('username' => <username>));
```

You can check in index action if id is an id or a username, and

- if it is a username, than fetch the user object and show profile,
- if it is an id, than fetch the user object and redirect like above

But you are also able to create two routes with constraints on the id part

```
for the username: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*
for the id: [0-9]+
```